# Read Claims from Automapper Value Resolver on NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I have a Automapper Mapping **Profile** like this:

```
CreateMap<MyViewModel, MyDto>()
.ForMember(s => s.MyProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CustomResolver>());
```

And this is my **CustomResolver** class (that aims to solve a value through the Claims):

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<object, object, string>
{
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public CompanyResolver(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public string Resolve(object source, object destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return "I will return here a value from Claims inside _context";
    }
}
```

Obviously, on my **Startup** class I registered my Services:

```
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

But, Always, I received this exception from Automapper:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

But, precisely, I want the request to go through the constructor (CustomResolver) with parameters because I want to receive IHttpContextAccesor instance.

What's wrong? Why is NET Core not capable of injecting the interface?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you clarify your answer? Thanks

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks, I solved the problem with your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **solved the problem** by changing this:

```
var automapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddProfile(new MyProfile());
});

var autoMapper = automapperConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(autoMapper);
```

To this:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(configuration =>
{
    configuration.AddProfile(new MyProfile());
});
```

I do not understand 100% the reason but I guess we should not add Automapper as Singleton